# How to know if an apex class or visual force page/component or lightning component was deleted?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, visualforce-component

How to know if an apex class or visual force page/component or lightning component was deleted? Is there a specific way to see which apex class/ visual force page/lightning components were deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Setup Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=5). It shows you all the changes that have been made to your org in the last 180 days - including changes (updates and deletes) to your Apex Classes, Components etc.